# Hide Summernote editor toolbar component

Tags: javascript, xamarin.android, summernote

I've implemented Summernote Editor `contentEditor` successfully, I aslo have a dropdownlist.

All I want is when dropdownlist `TopicId` is selected, video button in Editor toolbar is hidden

this is code in Create.cshtml file:

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 NoPadding">
   <div class="form-group">
       <label for="TopicId">Topic</label>
       <select name="TopicId" id="TopicId" class="form-control>
          <option value="">- Select -</option>
             @foreach (Topic t in ViewBag.TopicId)
               {
                 <option value="@t.Id" @(t.Id == Model.TopicId ? "selected" : "")>@t.Name </option>
               }
        </select>
   </div>
```

```
    <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom: 0px">
                    <label for="contentEditor">Content</label>
                    <div id="contentEditor"></div>
                    <textarea name="content" id="newsContent">@(Model?.Content)</textarea>
    </div>
```

[image]

This is javascript code within same file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            handleTopicChange();
            $('#TopicId').trigger('change');
        });

function handleTopicChange() {

            $("#TopicId").change(function () {
                var selectedTopicId = $(this).children(":selected").val();
                switch (selectedTopicId) {
                    case '4a0634d8-6597-4ca4-9f07-a4f50e7addeb':
                        $('.contentEditor').summernote({
                            toolbar: [
                                ['fontstyle', ['fontname', 'fontsize', 'color', 'bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strikethrough', 'superscript', 'subscript', 'deleteallformat']],
                                ['insert', ['picture', 'link', 'table', 'hr']],
                                ['para', ['style', 'ul', 'ol', 'paragraph', 'height']],
                                ['misc', ['undo', 'redo', 'codeview']],
                            ]
                        });
                        break;
                    default:
                        $('.contentEditor').summernote({
                            toolbar: [
                                ['fontstyle', ['fontname', 'fontsize', 'color', 'bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strikethrough', 'superscript', 'subscript', 'deleteallformat']],
                                ['insert', ['picture', 'link', 'video'. 'table', 'hr']],
                                ['para', ['style', 'ul', 'ol', 'paragraph', 'height']],
                                ['misc', ['undo', 'redo', 'codeview']],
                            ]
                        });
                        break;
                }

            });
        }
```

It doesn't work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery effects to show and hide icons by aria-label.

```
function handleTopicChange() {

        $("#TopicId").change(function () {
            var selectedTopicId = $(this).children(":selected").val();
            switch (selectedTopicId) {
                case '4a0634d8-6597-4ca4-9f07-a4f50e7addeb':
                    $(".note-insert button[aria-label*='Video']" ).hide();
                    break;
                default:
                    $(".note-insert button[aria-label*='Video']" ).show();
                    break;
            }

        });
    }
```